# PROBLEM encountered visual studio 2008 installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, installation

I installed Visual Studio 2008 package FULL option. It worked with out any problem. I installed Vstudio 2008 and MSDN in separate folder in the D drive. 2 days later in order to remove my projects i uninstalled every thing and also i deleted visual studio 2008, visual studio 2005 folders from C:\Documents and Settings\IRCTC\My Documents. (I believe these 2 folders were automatically created when we install visual studio) also I cleared %path% and path (c/windows/path). Again I installed VISUAL STUDIO 2008 but now I can't able to create window application (other web, vb also), what is the solution for this ...
ERROR that shown is

c:/documents and settings/IRCTC/local settings/temp/g1zzsdl.bak/temp/windowsFormsApplication.csproj cannot be opened because project type (.csproj) is not supported by this version of visual studio.......

Whether any system file corrupted (windows temp or .net folber in windows).....
No other installation problem found in my system.....
please help.....
What are the files/folders required for the installation......

Answer (score 1):

When you get that error is usually because:

1. **You are trying to open a project created with a previous version of Visual Studio** (not your case)
2. **There was a bit of a screw-up during the installation** (sounds like your case)

I'd uninstall the thing and reinstall completely first thing.

If it still doesn't work, it could be related to VS templates and you might wanna try and run from Visual Studio 2008 command prompt:

```
devenv /InstallVSTemplates
```

If it still doesn't work, open Visual Studio, in the menu, Open Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->General. At this point you will notice the path of Project Templates is set to "C:\Documents and Settings[yourUserName]\My Documents\Visual Studio 9\Templates\ProjectTemplates" or something very similar to that. In order to fix it you gotta set that path to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9\Common7\IDE\Project Templates or the same path according to wherever you installed Visual Studio

I don't think is related to VS project Templates though - see [this link](http://www.discussweb.com/server-management/10317-csproj-not-supported-version-visual-studio-2008-a.html)

Try and see what happens!

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you use visual studio's uninstall function available from the control panel|add/remove programs?

I would uninstall the latest installation as described above, and try again.

Comment: i tried that option also but i can't able to solve it. please read my question fully the following error coming.... i believe some files missing due to deletion of my folders

Comment: create a blank solution and add the .csproj as a project?